# How to set dynamically array object to the for loop in javascript when for loop iterates

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

I need to set my for loop length dynamically.

I have an object array.[image]

After my condition is true, I need to set dynamically objects in my permission array inside for loop.

Heare is my code:

```
if (obj[k]===pathData[i]){
         //pathData[i]=order
        for (let l = 0; l <permission[j].pathData[i].statusChange.length; l+=1) {
              
             } 
          }
```

My code is not working...I really need your help.

Comment: Please share the error logs along with the `permissions` object when the `if` statement is `true`

Comment: Would you like to use `map` or `foreEach` instead of `for` loop?

Comment: @Alexandr Belan
The problem is  permission[j].pathData[i] is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
var permissionObjKeys = Object.keys(permissions[j])
         for(permissionObjKey of permissionObjKeys){
            permissions[j][permissionObjKey].statusChange.push('new-permission')
         }
```

try this it will work inside the dynamic object present in the permission array.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Comment: considering pathData[i] = order means you know the key of the object. You can try this
permission[j][pathData[i]].statusChange.push('new-permission')

Comment: Sir That's not what I need. I need to set pathData[I] dynamically to my permission[j] array inside forloop

Comment: can you provid a more code snippet so that I can understand the problem correctly

Comment: That's all I have, To provide...I sm sorry. If my array has more objects than ordered, I need to set this object into one loop.